# Scheduling individual reports owned by a user

Tags: apex, reporting, scheduled-apex

Is there a way to schedule reports to a user on a daily basis on the opportunity he/she owns?

eg. I can schedule a report to be sent to one or may users,public groups using report scheduling feature in salesforce, but if I had to schedule reports specific to an individual how do I do it without using apex.

My solution: 1)Create a report and a custom formula with current logged in user's email address and say owneremail= customfield(logged in user email). This takes care of building reports specific to an user. (or) 2) My opportunities would give me all the reports related to me.

When I schedule the reports the report is built based on the user who schedules the report and sends to the group/ individual user the running users reports.

How do I schedule individual reports related to an user using a scheduler?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is not supported natively; a scheduled report shows the data as the running user.

Comment: That's what I thought, but was curious to know if someone had a workaround. I can build a apex scheduler and get this done like a charm. I will leave this open to see if someone has a solution, if not please post your comment as answer, I will accept it as best solution.

Comment: A 3rd party app might be able to help out.

Comment: @MikeChale Are you speaking about conga courier?

Comment: No; I haven't researched anything for this purpose but expect it's a common need so an app probably does exist.